# Determining Which Pattern Correlates with Each Sublist The Most

Tags: correlation

I would like to determine which pattern has the greatest correlation with each sublist.

I have the following data:

```
data = {{0.6043664420589688`, 0.9857728765270476`, 
0.5425821703751481`, 0.15504309122370524`, 
0.8276861413622156`}, {0.5425821703751481`, 0.15504309122370524`, 
0.8276861413622156`, 0.3117288541104692`, 
0.4230554403012381`}, {0.8276861413622156`, 0.3117288541104692`, 
0.4230554403012381`, 0.05368581732943603`, 
0.1285684468267231`}, {0.4230554403012381`, 0.05368581732943603`, 
0.1285684468267231`, 0.568487372004134`, 
0.9595968642236314`}, {0.1285684468267231`, 0.568487372004134`, 
0.9595968642236314`, 0.748598034746261`, 
0.5760672090376757`}, {0.9595968642236314`, 0.748598034746261`, 
0.5760672090376757`, 0.8226326906088341`, 
0.08882777194355806`}, {0.5760672090376757`, 0.8226326906088341`, 
0.08882777194355806`, 0.21758856941067833`, 
0.6896577869437517`}, {0.08882777194355806`, 0.21758856941067833`,
 0.6896577869437517`, 0.3515760303307617`, 
0.8666214369119132`}, {0.6896577869437517`, 0.3515760303307617`, 
0.8666214369119132`, 0.0015663158972453776`, 
0.6448673801479466`}, {0.8666214369119132`, 
0.0015663158972453776`, 0.6448673801479466`, 0.6775921340346936`, 
0.38830057970317`}, {0.6448673801479466`, 0.6775921340346936`, 
0.38830057970317`, 0.0875520713672823`, 
0.04050093808897781`}, {0.38830057970317`, 0.0875520713672823`, 
0.04050093808897781`, 0.6918192575076461`, 
0.8457184093280218`}, {0.04050093808897781`, 0.6918192575076461`, 
0.8457184093280218`, 0.9325089801435771`, 
0.21281479672676218`}, {0.8457184093280218`, 0.9325089801435771`, 
0.21281479672676218`, 0.3800904033971768`, 
0.42266296902678374`}, {0.21281479672676218`, 0.3800904033971768`,
 0.42266296902678374`, 0.878823162814141`, 
0.08424634990003906`}, {0.42266296902678374`, 0.878823162814141`, 
0.08424634990003906`, 0.8116030313930428`, 
0.46306610480315225`}, {0.08424634990003906`, 0.8116030313930428`,
 0.46306610480315225`, 0.1302251280678801`, 
0.5081791408623634`}, {0.46306610480315225`, 0.1302251280678801`, 
0.5081791408623634`, 0.9889703407842088`, 
0.3742383328595942`}, {0.5081791408623634`, 0.9889703407842088`, 
0.3742383328595942`, 0.9126365586572017`, 
0.8185213539186117`}, {0.3742383328595942`, 0.9126365586572017`, 
0.8185213539186117`, 0.6373943104534471`, 
0.507616895947681`}, {0.8185213539186117`, 0.6373943104534471`, 
0.507616895947681`, 0.9110702427599564`, 
0.17365397377066502`}, {0.507616895947681`, 0.9110702427599564`, 
0.17365397377066502`, 0.9598021764187534`, 
0.11931631624451103`}, {0.17365397377066502`, 0.9598021764187534`,
 0.11931631624451103`, 0.8235181713926741`, 
0.1331530356816872`}, {0.11931631624451103`, 0.8235181713926741`, 
0.1331530356816872`, 0.2679829189111074`, 0.2735979069164892`}};
```

I have a set of patterns which may fit certain sublists, found by taking the 3/4 and 1/4 quantiles at each position within each sublist, as follows:

```
aa = Quantile[data[[All, #]], 3/4] & /@ Table[i, {i, 1, 5}];
bb = Quantile[data[[All, #]], 1/4] & /@ Table[i, {i, 1, 5}];
patterns = Tuples[Transpose@{aa, bb}]
```

I would like to find which pattern (such as patterns[[1,All]]) has the greatest Absolute correlation (ie. correlation of -1 can be the greatest correlation) with each sublist in data.

I would like the output to follow the following format:

```
{{1,30}...{24,5}}
```

Where {1,30} represents sublist 1 having the highest correlation with pattern 30 (take into account that I did not check if this statement is true).

The data provided in this example is random as I am working with a much larger dataset and stackexchange will not allow me to post all of it. Thank you for your help!

EDIT: So far I have been able to calculate the correlations the following code found in a different answer on stackexchange:

```
N[Table[Map[Correlation[data[[i, All]], #] &, patterns], {i,Length[data]}]]
```

I can also find the Maximum points with:

```
datapatterncor =N[Table[Map[Correlation[data[[i, All]], #] &, patterns], {i, 
 Length[data]}]];
```

But I still cannot find a way to automate the process of finding the positions of the values with the greatest distance from zero in each sublist.

Comment: Have a look at `ListCorrelate`.

Comment: @bills ListCorrelate seems to be multiplying each value in each pattern by the value in the equivalent position in data. Am I doing something wrong? It isn't returning the correlation between two lists.

Comment: Correction, it seems to be multiplying as stated before and then adding the values in each resulting sublist.

Comment: Have you tried `Correlation` ?

Comment: Your comment actually reminded me of a previous recommendation from a past question to map the correlation function over the data (shown in the edited portion of the question). Now I just need to find the position of the value with the greatest distance from zero each sublist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this give the result you need?

```
Transpose[{Range[24], Last@*Ordering /@ Outer[Abs@*Correlation, data, patterns, 1]}]

(* {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 17}, {4, 4}, {5, 16}, {6, 31}, {7, 7}, {8, 27}, 
   {9, 11}, {10, 23}, {11, 4}, {12, 4}, {13, 15}, {14, 8}, {15, 30},
   {16, 5}, {17, 19}, {18, 3}, {19, 21}, {20, 20}, {21, 14}, {22, 32},
   {23, 22}, {24, 24}} *)
```

Comment: This works too! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I apologize if I have misunderstood the aim. In the following are two approaches. The first uses absolute correlation as distance function  to generate a distance matrix and the major diagonal is removed. Thereafter, the position of element with maximal correlation for each list. The second approach uses `Nearest` and -absolute correlation as distance to identify 'closes'list.

```
dm = DistanceMatrix[data, 
    DistanceFunction -> (Abs@Correlation[#1, #2] &)] - 
   IdentityMatrix[24];
mx = Max /@ dm;
un = MapThread[{#1, Position[#2, #3][[1, 1]]} -> #3 &, {Range[24], dm,
     mx}];
dmr = ReplacePart[dm, Thread[Keys[un] -> 10]];
Legended[MatrixPlot[dmr, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  ColorRules -> {10 -> Black, 0. -> White}], BarLegend["Rainbow"]]
nf[u_] := {u, 
  Position[data, 
    Nearest[data, data[[u]], 2, 
      DistanceFunction -> (-Abs@Correlation[#1, #2] &)][[-1]]][[1, 1]]}
nfv = nf /@ Range[24];
Keys[un] == nfv
```

[image]

Comment: This is really neat! I will take a look at it after breakfast to see if I can breakdown how the code works and I'll let you know if it is returning the solutions I am aiming for!

Comment: @AlejandroBraun I may have misunderstood. It is after midnight in my timezone so I am off to bed.:)

Comment: It seems like what I was looking for, I will update if it isn't. Thank you for your help!